# Ubuntu Server, network config, cant connect

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I have Ubuntu server edition installed

I have setup 2 nic's

The one on the local network works perfectly but the one connecting to the internet is not working properly, I can't ping and domain name's aren't getting resolved.

My /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#Internal
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.X
    netmask 255.255.255.0

#External
iface eth1 inet static
    address 41.161.0.XXX
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    gateway 41.161.0.XXX
```

I have tried stopping, starting the nics, my iptables are set to

```
iptables --flush
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

I can not ping the gateway any ideas?

EDIT:

The settings are as provided by the ISP, the settings work perfectly on my mac and on my windows machine, which is both disconnected from that network at the moment so there can't be IP conflicts

Netstat:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination        Gateway        Genmask          Flags        MSS  Window   irtt Iface
0.0.0.0            41.161.2.XXX   0.0.0.0          UG             0  0           0 eth1
41.161.2.XXX       0.0.0.0        255.255.255.248  U              0  0           0 eth1
169.254.0.0        0.0.0.0        255.255.0.0      U              0  0           0 eth1
192.168.0.0        0.0.0.0        255.255.255.0    U              0  0           0 eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the actual configuration using `ifconfig eth1`.

Make sure the gateway is in the same subnet as the eth1 address. (Please edit your question and unobscure the netmask and the local part (last few X) of the addresses)

Check routing using `netstat -nr`

Check your configuration with with the persons who provide the gateway router.